# How to change programatically top bar background swift 4 on iOS 13

Tags: swift, statusbar, ios13, navigationbar, uicolor

I want to change the status and navigation bar from colored to transparent and from transparent to colored.
How can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwlg5.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .green // Set Background Color
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .none  // remove Background Color
```

Comment: try .clean @RFComp